# Xcode shortcut to move cursor to next method

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

There are so many fantastic, yet slightly obscure, Xcode shortcuts (e.g., ⇧⌘C jump to console) that I'm hoping this one exists, but I've had no luck tracking it down just yet: is there a shortcut to move the cursor to the next method in a source file? Thanks for reading.

---

Note: I'm aware of ⌃6 letting me navigate directly to a method by name, but this is subtly different and would act more like a "jump by paragraph"-type shortcut. (And it'd *potentially* involve much fewer keystrokes, depending on method names, positions, etc.).

Comment: I would love to answer this, but I found [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794906/is-there-a-way-to-jump-to-a-specific-method-in-xcode). There is also a [blog post](http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/9/15/14-xcode-time-saving-shortcuts-memorize-and-improve-your-productivity) here that has some cool stuff in it.

Comment: This was available in ObjectMaster which not only could keyboard to each routine or method, but also open up an editor window that that was focused to a given routine or method (completely opposite of the browser approach in Xcode).  Xcode is woefully behind 17 years later.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such shortcut within xCode [xCode Shortcuts and Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html).  If you double click on the opening bracket { of the method it will highlight the method content and the end bracket }.  This will at least allow you to quickly see where the next method starts.